# I outsourced some work and my project is now back from the Android Developer and he has changed the package name and now my Gradle won't work?

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, android-gradle-plugin, firebase-authentication

I have changed everything by refactoring my package name to the original name by refactoring my package name and also, again with Firebase Auth in terms of Facebook Login, Google Login, and Phone Login.

But I cannot seem to sync my Gradle as it shows these messages

> Gradle project sync failed.  Basic functionality will not work
>   properly.

```js
Error: Could not find com.android.tools.build: gradle: 3.0 .0 - alpha5.
Searched in the following locations:
  file: /C:/Program
Files / Android / Android Studio / gradle / m2repository / com / android / tools / build / gradle / 3.0 .0 - alpha5 / gradle - 3.0 .0 - alpha5.pom
file: /C:/Program
Files / Android / Android Studio / gradle / m2repository / com / android / tools / build / gradle / 3.0 .0 - alpha5 / gradle - 3.0 .0 - alpha5.jar
https: //jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-3.0.0-alpha5.pom
  https: //jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0-alpha5/gradle-3.0.0-alpha5.jar
  Required by:
  project:
```

**Android 2.3.3**

Answer (score 1):

in your top `build.gradle` you should add this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

and remove line which contains `alpha`. That developer must be using canary builds of Android studio.